# Can't create unique constraint in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I am attempt to create a constraint like this:

```
CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:forecast) ASSERT a.match IS UNIQUE
```

but I get this error:

> Unable to create Constraint( name='constraint_9615361a',
> type='UNIQUENESS', schema=(:forecast {match}) ):

I have the Neo4J community edition 4.2.3, but judging by the documentation I should be allowed to create this type of constraint. What gives?

Comment: Is that all there is to the error? Usually when a unique constraint can't be applied, it would mention what nodes found have the same property values.

Comment: That's all there is to the error. I can replace "forecast" with something made-up and it would still give the same error

Comment: Check your debug logs for anything useful. One possible reason a constraint can't be created could be a permission or ownership issue for some directory or file, maybe your index or schema directories.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if there is uniqueness on forecast {match} by running this.

```
MATCH (a:forecast) 
RETURN a.match, count(*) LIMIT 5
```

If you see a value > 1 in count() then forecast.match is not unique.

Note: count() is sorting in descending order in my desktop. In case it is not, then run below:

```
MATCH (a:forecast) 
WITH a.match as match, count(*) as cnt
RETURN match, cnt ORDER by cnt DESC LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Late reply, but still.

I was struck by the same error now (with 4.4.3) and it was lack of free space on drive.

Wasted half an hour, digging in absolutely wrong direction.
I create database with --skip-duplicate-nodes=true flag, so of course there couldn't be any duplicates.